# Not able to deploy .war file to Tomcat on AWS Instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

Today I tried deploying my simple Spring MVC web app to AWS instance. I installed the tomcat server and started successfully on the instance. I am able to access the tomcat home page from my browser.
When I tried uploading the .war file and clicked deploy, it got uploaded successfully but I am not able to start the application.

I am receiving the following error message when clicking on Start.

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? Please assist.

### Catalina logs

```
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_282-b08
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Red Hat, Inc.
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.281 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.285 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.285 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68/conf/logging.properties
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68/temp
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.435 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.472 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.509 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1258 ms
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.562 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/8.5.68]
20-Jun-2021 05:28:53.585 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68/webapps/ROOT]
20-Jun-2021 05:28:54.052 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [467] ms
20-Jun-2021 05:28:54.053 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68/webapps/docs]
20-Jun-2021 05:28:54.091 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68/webapps/docs] has finished in [38] ms
20-Jun-2021 05:28:54.096 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.68/webapps/examples]
```

Comment: Please include the log files in the question (check `catalina.<date>.log` and `localhost.<date>.log`.

Comment: Can you please check now? I have included Catalina logs.

Comment: The logs contain the deployment of the standard application, but not your application. Look for `Deploying web application...` or check the `manager.<date>.log` file.

Comment: It got resolved. <absolute-ordering/> this tag was missing in my web.xml. After I included it worked fine.